# Can't get html5 video seek button to work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I built a web video player with HTML5, it works but the seek button doesn't. I want it to work as well. My script:

```
    <?php
    include 'theme.php';
    ceklogin();
    function getFiles($path = 'mnt') {

        // Open the path set
        if ($handle = opendir($path)){

            // Loop through each file in the directory
            while ( false !== ($file = readdir($handle)) ) {

                // Remove the . and .. directories
                if ( $file != "." && $file != ".." ) {

                    // Check to see if the file is a directory
                    if( is_dir($path . '/' . $file) ) {

                        // The file is a directory, therefore run a dir check again
                        getFiles($path . '/' . $file);

                    }

                    // Get the information about the file
                    $fileInfo = pathinfo($file);

                    // Set multiple extension types that are allowed
                    $allowedExtensions = array('mkv', 'mp4','MKV','MP4');

                    // Check to ensure the file is allowed before returning the results
                    if( in_array($fileInfo['extension'], $allowedExtensions) ) {
                        echo '<li class="active"><a href="' . $path . '/' . $file . '">' . $file . '</a></li>';
                    }

                }
            }

            // Close the handle
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }
    css();
    echo '
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var msg = "OpenWrt Angel Beats! Edition";
    msg = " | " + msg;pos = 0;
    function scrollTitle() {
    document.title = msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + msg.substring(0, pos); pos++;
    if (pos > msg.length) pos = 0
    window.setTimeout("scrollTitle()",300);
    }
    scrollTitle();
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .......................
    </style>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
    var video;
    var playlist;
    var tracks;
    var current;

    $(document).ready(function() {
     init();
    });
    function init(){
       current = 0;
       video = $("video");
       playlist = $("#playlist");
       tracks = playlist.find("li a");
       len = tracks.length - 1;
       video[0].volume = .50;
       video[0].play();
       playlist.find("a").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           link = $(this);
           current = link.parent().index();
           run(link, video[0]);
       });
       video[0].addEventListener("ended",function(e){
           current++;
           if(current == len){
               current = 0;
               link = playlist.find("a")[0];
           }else{
               link = playlist.find("a")[current];    
           }
           run($(link),video[0]);
       });
    }
    function run(link, player){
           player.src = link.attr("href");
           par = link.parent();
           par.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
           video[0].load();
           video[0].play();
    }
    seekToTime:function( value )
{
    var seekToTime = this.videoPlayer.currentTime + value;
    if( seekToTime < 0 || seekToTime > this.videoPlayer.duration ) 
        return;

    this.videoPlayer.currentTime = seekToTime;
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <video id="videoarea" controls="controls" poster="/images/video-poster.jpg" src=""></video>
    <ul id="playlist">';
    getFiles();
    echo '
    </ul>
    <br>
    <b>Supported file formats: *.mkv and *.mp4</b>
    </div>';
    foot();
    echo '
    </body>
    </html>';
    ?>
```

I have tried adding:

```
seekToTime:function( value )
{
    var seekToTime = this.videoPlayer.currentTime + value;
    if( seekToTime < 0 || seekToTime > this.videoPlayer.duration ) 
        return;

    this.videoPlayer.currentTime = seekToTime;
}
```

in the `head` of the html but it doesn't work, I must have implemented that code wrong, how should I make it work?

Comment: Yes, the videos won't play at all when I use that `seekToTime` part, I'm sure I implemented the code wrong, please help...

Comment: `seekToTime:function( value )` is valid inside object definition, `this.videoPlayer` is undefined. Seems like copy&paste without understanding what it is doing.

Comment: Yes @Marek, I'm sorry, I'm still learning about javascript, I need your help to fix it.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`